# is DCPU-16 assembler 'dat' with a string supposed to generate a byte or word per character?

Tags: dcpu-16

It's not clear to me whether

`dat "Hello"`

is supposed to generate 5 words or 3 (with one byte of padding)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

according to [this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfmsm.jpg) it is one word per 8 bit character:

so

```
:data dat 0x170, "Hello ", 0x2e1 ...
```

will generate

```
0x0170 0x0048 0x0065 0x006c 0x006c 0x006f 0x0020 0x02e1
```

etc.

he tests the difference between normal chars and the special chars with

```
ifg a, 0xff
```

this would conclude that all ascii char will have its own word

Comment: yep, that's how I've gone and implemented it in https://github.com/jtauber/dcpu16py